# Getting the template correctly in Mustache

Tags: javascript, jquery, mustache

I am new to Mustache and I have a question in regard to converting script file to template correctly.

Assume that I have the following file

```
<script type="text/template" id="template-member-list-item">
   {{#item_data}}
      <tr id="{{user_login}}">
      </tr>
   {{/item_data}}
</script>
```

to get this file into html correctly, can I go like this?

```
var template = jQuery(above.html)[0].innerHTML;
var html = Mustache.to_html(template, JSON file);
jQuery('#content').append(html);
```

would this be correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is call Enumerable Section with Objects 
We always use below section to iterate collection in Mustache 
{{#}}
{{/}}

Html will remain same

```
   <script type="text/template" id="template-member-list-item">
     {{#item_data}}
    <tr id="{{user_login}}">
     </tr>
    {{/item_data}}
   </script>
```

JSON input will be look like

```
 var data = {
      item_data: [
{   user_login: "Christophe"},
{   user_login: "John"}
]};
```

Here is rendering of html template

```
 var template = $("#template-member-list-item").html();
 var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
 $('#content').html(html);
```

For more detail example see below link 
http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/tutorial-html-templates-with-mustache-js/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://zeptojs.com/zepto.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/0.8.1/mustache.js" ></script>
<div id="content"></div>
<script type="text/template" id="template-member-list-item">
   {{#item_data}}
      <tr id="name">
        {{user_login}}
      </tr>
   {{/item_data}}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var tpl = $("#template-member-list-item").html()
    var html=Mustache.render(tpl,{item_data:{user_login:"test_user"}})
    $("#content").html(html)
})
</script>
```